# How can I alternate styles between paragraphs in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I tried :nth-of-type but I'm not sure if is even possible, or if that feature makes what I really want. I need an alternating style: two paragraphs aligned on the left, followed by two on the right, and so on, even if I add new paragraphs.

This gives a rough idea of what I mean:

```
Paragraph

Paragraph

             Paragraph

             Paragraph
Paragraph

Paragraph

             Paragraph

             Paragraph
```

Comment: So you're looking for an alternating pattern for styles to be applied to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```css
p {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
}
p:nth-of-type(4n+3), p:nth-of-type(4n+4) {
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 4</p>
<p>paragraph 5</p>
<p>paragraph 6</p>
<p>paragraph 7</p>
<p>paragraph 8</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
p:nth-child(4n),
p:nth-child(4n-1)
{ text-align: right; }
```

[Working pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myRpZJ)

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around nth-child(4n+x)

One possible solution...

```
p:nth-child(4n+1), P:nth-child(4n+2) {
  // left styles
}
p:nth-child(4n+3), p:nth-child(4n+4) {
  // right styles
}
```